# Reading characters from a File with fscanf

Tags: c++, c, file, char, scanf

I have a problem, using fscanf function :(
I need to reed a sequence of characters from file like "a b c d" (characters are separated by space).

but it doesn't works :(
how I have to read them? (

I tried to print it and the result is uncorrect. I think, it's because of spaces. I really don't know why it doesn't work.

Tell me please, what is wrong with array access?

Comment: Likely not consuming white space but I don't know `fscanf()` well enough to say for sure. You say "it doesn't work", how so? What's wrong with it, like, what does it do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: The characters are put in the array `alpArr`. If you don't know how to access an array in C, there are plenty of tutorials on the internet...

Comment: It seems correct for me. The error might be somewhere else. Do you try print the alpArr array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add white space before %c =>

```
while (fscanf(pFile," %c", &alpArr[i++]) == 1);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/):

> The function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).

Then if your code is:

```
while ( fscanf(fin,"%c", &array[i++]) == 1 );
```

and your file contains the following string:

`h e l l o`

Your `array` will be:

`[h][ ][e][ ][l][ ][l][ ][o]`

If you change your code into:

```
while ( fscanf(fin," %c", &array[i++]) == 1 );
```

with the same file, your `array` will be:

`[h][e][l][l][o]`

In any case the code works: it depends on what you want.

Anyway, you should think about starting to use `fgets()` + `sscanf()`, for example:

```
char buff[NUM];

while ( fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fin) )
    sscanf(buff,"%c", &array[i++]);
```

With the single `fscanf()` the lack of buffer management can turns into buffer overflow problems.