# How to store characters from a file into an array

Tags: c

Please I have had a lot of trouble with this. I have a text file with tons of characters in it and I need to read through each character and if it is a letter of the alphabet then I need to store it in an array.

So far I have just tried to put the character in my array regardless if it is an alphabet character or not but my fscanf isn't reading anything.

Here is my code

```
    char j = ' ';
    int i;

    FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      fscanf(file, " %c ", &j);
      printf(" %c\n", j); //So I could see if j got anything BUT I'M NOT :(
      if((j >= '97' && j <= '122') || (j >= '65' && j <= '90'))
      {
         fscanf(file, "%c", &array[i]);
      }
    }

fclose(file);
return 0;
```

My result? Nothing just blank spaces. Yes my text file is in the same folder as my .c file

help

**MY ISSUE: My fscanf isn't actually reading anything. My j variable never changes! The ASCII thingy I can fix now thanks to the helpers below, but fscanf is my main issue that is stopping my progress**

Comment: Please show the code you have.

Comment: Use `fgetc` in a loop.

Comment: and Use `isalpha`.

Comment: [Use a library -- they solve everything!](https://github.com/welcome-me/readstr) ... Ha, ha. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  We'll help you fix your honest attempt at solving your problem, but we won't usually just write the code ab initio.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), though it is likely that your code is already effectively an MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem:

```
/* WRONG */
if((j >= '97' && j <= '122') || (j >= '65' && j <= '90'))

/* CORRECT */
if((j >= 97 && j <= 122) || (j >= 65 && j <= 90))
```

In other words, the expressions `'A'`, `'\0x41'` and `65` are all equivalent in this context.

But '65' isn't.  It means the character "ASCII 6" and "ASCII 6" - such a character doesn't exist :(

PS:
As Bluepixy suggested, [isalpha()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) is your friend.  I encourage you to substitute `isalpha()` in your code.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! One Q though, how come my printf (which is before my if statement) isn't printing anything but the line spaces? my variable j hasn't changed at all throughout the loop! I made sure my text file had characters in it and it does. How come my j isn't storing them

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the code here, and check for character through isalnum() function

```
char *readFileCharacter(char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    int c;
    char *code;
    size_t n = 0;

    if (file == NULL) 
           return NULL; //impossible to open file

    // Get the size of the file to allocate correctly the array of char
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long f_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    code = malloc(f_size);

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if ( isalnum(c) ) // check if alphanum
          code[n++] = (char)c;
    }
    fclose(file);
    code[n] = '\0';        

    return code;
}
```

Comment: Hey this is pretty cool BUT is all very advanced for me :( Is there any simpler and more basic way to do this for beginners. Maybe with fscanf or something similar. I added my code above so you can see what level i'm at

Comment: Very easy code, the only thing is that you have to be agnostic regarding the size of your file. Then allocation is dynamic and depending of the size of the file. You can also change `if ( isalnum(c) ) ` by `if((c >= 97 && c <= 122) || (c >= 65 && c <= 90))`. This should work for you.

Comment: Hey thanks so much! One Q though, how come my printf (which is before my if statement) isn't printing anything but the line spaces? my variable j hasn't changed at all throughout the loop! I made sure my text file had characters in it and it does. How come my j isn't storing them

Comment: remove spaces in your fscanf statement : `fscanf(file, "%c", &j);` should be better.

Comment: Unfortunate no it didn't help :( Why won't this fscanf work :(                                My text file has abcdefgdidjoeinfoiwn3923829032 etc.

Comment: use the dedicated function `fgetc` (as shown in my code)

Comment: @kapra if you refer to this post [Reading characters from a File with fscanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243094/reading-characters-from-a-file-with-fscanf) you have to change the format of reading with fscanf by `fscanf(" %c", &j);`